# SD card SPI initialization Check Pattern Fail

Tags: embedded, sd

I'm trying to interface a Swissbit 512MB (S-450u Series) SD card (datasheet [here](https://www.swissbit.com/data/view.php?q=S-450u/S-450u_fact_sheet.pdf)) with an ARM microcontroller through the card's SPI interface. The datasheet for this card says it's fully compliant with SD Spec v3. When I send CMD0, I get the expected response. But when I send CMD8 with check pattern=0x1AA and CRC=0x87, I get the response 0x21F, even though the card is supposed to echo the check pattern.

This has been discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21269932/sd-over-spi-returns-invalid-response-on-cmd8), but the accepted response doesn't make any sense, and doesn't work for me either. I haven't been able to find anything in the SD Card Simplified Spec to describe malformed check pattern responses. If I received the Illegal Command flag, I would know that this is a version 1 card, but I don't receive that flag, just the malformed check pattern. The card works just fine when I plug it into my PC and format as FAT. I've tried with a Samsung card and I get the same result.

I also have tried sending SCK pulses before each transmission, while CS is high, as suggested by many people.

**What causes malformed check pattern responses in SD cards?**

[This is a screenshot of the dummy cycles for resetting the card.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z492B.png)

[This is a screenshot of CMD0 and response.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sBxby.png)

[This is a screenshot of CMD8 and response.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UL0aR.png)

EDIT: The SD card and the microcontroller were previously being powered from 2 different supplies. Now I've switched to powering them off of the same supply, and they draw about 30mA at 3V. This hasn't changed the SD card's response to CMD8. However, I have noticed that if I send CMD55 after CMD8, the SD card responds with the R1 response of 0x03 (idle bit and erase reset bit on). I'm not sure if this is a useful hint though, or just barking up the wrong tree.